# Error 404 - connect to Gmail API from MVC Application

Tags: gmail-api

I have problem. I try to connect with Gmail API from my MVC application. On my local machine all works fine but when I deploy application to IIS I get 404 error. It is caused by redirect application to "http://localhost/AuthCallback/IndexAsync"  address when the correct is "http://localhost/myApplicationName/AuthCallback/IndexAsync".

Can I change default redirect url?

I get error after user authorization.

I'm using Google.Apis Version 1.9.1.12395 and GoogleApis.Gmail.v1 version 1.9.0.31.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Mariusz! Have you tried changing the redirect URL of your application in the Google Developer Console? https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Hi, Yes I did this. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I resolve problem. I had to override parameter in class **AppFlowMetadata**

```
public override string AuthCallback
{
get
    {
        return @"/ApplicationName/AuthCallback/IndexAsync";
    }
}
```